# is using [current-page:query:service_name] token is safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: webforms, tokens

I'm using [current-page:query:service_name] token in my project to get parameters from the url into the database (using webforms and tokens).

I was looking in the code to check if there is some kind of sanitazing but i can't find one.. I need to know if it is safe to use it, without being worried about SQL Injection, and if it is not safe, I would like a help of how to sanitize this token with some kind of preg_replace sentence.

Comment: Probably its using prepared statements, and such statements are safe from injections. Are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: probably? can you add a reference please?